# How Can I Edit entries from multiple tables using Datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have kind of a multi part question here..

1. I am looking to display data from multiple tables in a Datagridview using INNER JOIN and when the user selects a row in the grid the data populates text boxes on the form for editing as if it were bound to just one table. Below is the code I am using to populate the datagridview.
2. For some of the tickets including the pqr and cwb there can be multiple entries for one Welder,  how can I display all of the entries for each ticket beneath each Welder if there are more than one?
3. When the DataGrid is populated by the dataset it populates the column headers with with the Column names from the tables, is there a way to alter the Column names within the SQL statement or do I have to manually build the grid and the columns somehow?

   ```
      Dim cs As String = My.Settings.MacroQualityConnectionString
   Dim sqlweld As String = <a>
       SELECT 
       Employee_Names.First_Name, Employee_Names.Last_Name, Welding_Journeyman.Journeyman_Certified, Welding_Journeyman.Journeyman_Number,
       Welding_Journeyman.Journeyman_Province, Welding_CWB.CWB_Certified, Welding_CWB.CWB_Expiry,
       Welding_PQR.PQR_Process, Welding_PQR.PQR_Wall_Thickness_Min, Welding_PQR.PQR_Wall_Thickness_Max, Welding_PQR.PQR_OD_Min,
       Welding_PQR.PQR_OD_Max, Welding_PQR.PQR_Expiry, Welding_Certifications.File_Name

       FROM 
       Employee_Names 

       INNER JOIN Welders ON Welders.employeeID = Employee_Names.employeeID 
       INNER JOIN Welding_Journeyman ON Welders.welderID = Welding_Journeyman.journeymanID
       INNER JOIN Welding_CWB ON Welders.welderID = Welding_CWB.cwbID
       INNER JOIN Welding_PQR ON Welders.welderID = Welding_PQR.pqr1ID
       INNER JOIN Welding_Certifications ON Welders.welderID = Welding_Certifications.weldingcertsID

   </a>
   Dim connection As New SqlConnection(cs)
   Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlweld, connection)

   connection.Open()
   dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Welders")
   connection.Close()

   DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
   ```

My knowledge of SQL is quite limited I am working hard at trying to wrap my head around all of this so please bear with me if I have some dumb questions!!  Thanks everyone in advance for your input!
This is for a vb.net desktop application connecting to Microsoft Azure Database and Storage.

Comment: to alter the names for Headers just put it like Select Employee_Names.First_Name as FirstName, ...    you are actually creating a view with your Query and if you want child information indented to be shown under the parent you need another control. Datagridview is a single Band Control .. but you can accomplish this with a tree but not like this tho

Comment: If a welder had two tickets of type pqr would there be a way to display the welders name twice and each different pqr entry with each name?